# How to call .Net Core API from Logic App using HTTP or HTTP + Swagger

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps

I have created a Logic App which gets trigger when I receive a mail in my outlook inbox folder.
If the mail doesn't have an attachment then I need to call my .net core API (.net core API build in 2.1 version) which will pick up the file from the FTP server and dump it in my Azure storage container.

When I hit the .net core API URL through postman (postman URL - https://example.net/api/Email/1) then I am able to fetch the file from FTP and dump it to the azure storage container.
Now I am getting an error when I tried to do the same thing through the logic app HTTP request.
Scenario 1 - With HTTP Action. (With Application URL)
When I tried to hit the same postman URL using HTTP action then it's not working and giving the below error

[image]

On getting the above error I tried giving it valid JSON data which is https://example.net/swagger/v1/swagger.json. Now, this is returning me a successful response with 200 code, but this is not performing the task (i.e uploading a file from FTP to Azure storage container).

Scenario 2 with HTTP + Swagger.
I have tried with HTTP + Swagger for this. But in this, I am getting below error when I tried to hit this URL - https://example.net/swagger/v1/swagger.json
Enable Cors. for the swagger Endpoints.
I have tried multiple things to enable cors, but all in vain.
[image]